# The value of the definite integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^a)(1+x^2)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> The value of the definite integral 
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^a)(1+x^2)}$$ $(a>0)$ is?

**MY ATTEMPTS:**

1)Partial Fraction-Not possible

2)Substitutions-Could'nt think of any

3)General rules for changing limits of integration do not seem to work.

**Any suggestions/hints?**

Comment: Are you familiar with complex methods?

Comment: This was asked several times very recently. Must be the season... (And no, complex analysis is not required.)

Comment: @Did Could you please add those duplicates here?Might help future users.Google search showed no results btw..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

... always the same. By the substitution $x=\frac{1}{z}$ we have

$$I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^\alpha)(1+x^2)}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{(1+z^{-\alpha})(1+z^2)} $$
hence
$$ 2\,I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^\alpha}+\frac{1}{1+x^{-\alpha}}\right)\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}. $$
*A symmetry trick suddenly appears*: $I(\alpha)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}$.

Comment: a few months back I asked for more examples of this symmetry trick. Behold! Another one, that funny enough evaluates to the same thing as $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\tan(x)^{\alpha}+1}$$ (which make some sense)

Comment: @AndresMejia So what substitution you made for this?'

Comment: Use the definition of $\tan $ and $x=\pi/2-x $. Same symmetry trick

Comment: $\pi/2-y $, im sorry